# Why doesn't smartbear offer SOAP UI v 5.4.0?

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I would like to download SOAP UI version 5.4.0 (once had this version installed) but now this version (and all versions between 5.2.1 and 5.5.0) is missing on https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/soapui-os-older-versions/ - do you know why?

Comment: It probably has to do with the purchase of SoapUI or java versions. Have a look here, there is a link that works: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source-Questions/SoapUI-Open-Source-Download-Link-Broken-for-Version-5-4-0/td-p/173984

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to work. Could download it for Windows. Maybe you also know where to get the one for Mac OS?